# addEventListener in ionic 3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I need to read sms on it arrive. I get cordova-plugin-sms and use this code. But how i could change this code in order to work in ionic 3?

```
if(window.SMS){ 
    window.SMS.startWatch(data => {
        console.log('watching', 'watching started');
    }, error => {
        console.log('failed to start watching');
    });
}

document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e) {
    var sms = e.data;
    console.log(sms);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is not meant to read/receive/listen to SMS.

From the [FAQ section of the repo](https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin):

> ### How can I receive SMS?
>
> You can't receive SMS via this plugin. This plugin only sends SMS.

Answer (score 0):

There is a major difference between the plugins

cordova-sms-plugin and
cordova-plugin-sms

the last one supports receiving SMS, but not the first

Answer (score -1):

There are some [open issues](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/issues/74) with cordova-plugin-sms and Ionic 3 compatibility.

You can use an alternate plugin **[cordova-plugin-sms-receive](https://github.com/andreszs/cordova-plugin-sms-receive)**

It has below code that you can use in your app for receiving sms:

Event: **onSMSArrive**

Triggered when a new SMS has arrived. You need call startWatch() first.

```
/* Initialize incoming SMS event listener */
document.addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e) {
    console.log('onSMSArrive()');
    var IncomingSMS = e.data;
    console.log('sms.address:' + IncomingSMS.address);
    console.log('sms.body:' + IncomingSMS.body);
    /* Debug received SMS content (JSON) */
    console.log(JSON.stringify(IncomingSMS));
});
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: hi, i added new information, does that count? thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try with following change-

```
if((<any>window).SMS){ 
    (<any>window).SMS.startWatch(data => {
        console.log('watching', 'watching started');
    }, error => {
        console.log('failed to start watching');
    });
}

(<any>window).addEventListener('onSMSArrive', function(e) {
    var sms = e.data;
    console.log(sms);
});
```